# Javascript isnull

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

This is a really great function written in jQuery to determine the value of a url field:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}

// example.com?someparam=name&otherparam=8&id=6
$.urlParam('someparam'); // name
$.urlParam('id'); // 6
$.urlParam('notavar'); // null
```

http://snipplr.com/view/11583/retrieve-url-params-with-jquery/

I would like to add a condition to test for null, but this looks kind of klunky:

```
if (results == null) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Q: What's the elegant way to accomplish the above if/then statement?

Comment: lol, exact piece of code I was about to ask the exact question on. 3yrs later

Comment: The test for `results[1]` would be unnecessary, since if `results` is non-null, it means the regexp succeeded, which means the first captured group was also found. So all you need is `results ? results[1] : 0`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
return results == null ? 0 : (results[1] || 0);
```

Comment: @Brad What is (results[1] || 0)? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Its the object at index position 1 in 'results' or the value 0.

Comment: Brad, try use `.test()` is best

Answer (score 13):

```
return results == null ? 0 : ( results[1] || 0 );
```

Comment: @DDaviesBrackett: it doesn't:

    js> results = null;
    null
    js> results[1] || 0;
    typein:2: TypeError: results has no properties

Comment: Well, it looks like you answered first, so you're getting my upvote.

Comment: On second thoughts, I'm not sure whether the comparison to null is the  most readable approach and I think I'd prefer something like

    return results instanceof Array ? ( results[1] || 0 ) : 0

Answer (score 5):

the most terse solution would be to change `return results[1] || 0;` to `return (results && results[1]) || 0`.

Comment: I'm getting an error "results is null" in firebug if I return results[1] || 0

Comment: No need for the parens, that's the default precedence, so `results && results[1] || 0`.

Comment: Too late for Phillip but I'll bite: && is a short circuit "and" operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
if(typeof(results) == "undefined") { 
    return 0;
} else {
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof(results)!='undefined'){ 
    return results[1];
} else { 
    return 0; 
};
```

But you might want to check if results is an array. Arrays are of type Object so you will need this [function](http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html)

```
function typeOf(value) {
    var s = typeof value;
    if (s === 'object') {
        if (value) {
            if (value instanceof Array) {
                s = 'array';
            }
        } else {
            s = 'null';
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

So your code becomes

```
if (typeOf(results)==='array'){
      return results[1];
}
else
{
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return results==null ? 0 : ( results[1] || 0 );
```

Comment: You've just rewritten the code provided by the OP to use the ternary operator instead of `if`.

Answer (score 2):

```
return (results||0) && results[1] || 0;
```

The && operator acts as guard and returns the 0 if results if falsy and return the rightmost part if truthy.

Answer (score 2):

All mentioned solutions are legit but if we're talking about elegance then I'll pitch in with the following example:

```
//function that checks if an object is null
var isNull = function(obj) {
  return obj == null;
}            

if(isNull(results)){
 return 0;
} else {
  return results[1] || 0;
}
```

Using the isNull function helps the code be more readable.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the style

```
(results || [, 0]) [1]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does indeed provide an explicit answer to the question. It is not a critique or request for clarification. In what sense is it not an answer? It is a construct I use all the time to deal with the precise question asked by the OP, which is how to deal concisely with a `null` result from `RegExp#exec`.

Comment: I like this answer best because I can't find a way to misinterpret it AND, importantly, the default answer (0) is specified only once.  Many coding errors are introduced when a particular magic number appears in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try `.test()` ? ... Try its and best boolean (true or false):

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    return results.test(window.location.href);
}
```

**Tutorial:** 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this function

```
function isNull() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (
            typeof arguments[i] !== 'undefined'
            && arguments[i] !== undefined
            && arguments[i] != null
            && arguments[i] != NaN
            && arguments[i] 
        ) return arguments[i];
      }
}
```

test

```
console.log(isNull(null, null, undefined, 'Target'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the not operator. It will check if a variable is null, or, in the case of a string, is empty. It makes your code more compact and easier to read.

For example:

```
var pass = "";
if(!pass)
    return false;
else
    return true;
```

This would return false because the string is empty. It would also return false if the variable pass was null.